# How to convert an instance of user-defined class to a tuple

Tags: python

I have an imaginary class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, **values):
        self._value_tuple = tuple(values.items())
```

And I would like to be able to convert it to `tuple` using built-in constructor:

```
>>> foo = Foo(ham=1, eggs=2, spam=3)
>>> tuple(foo)
(('ham', 1), ('eggs', 2), ('spam', 3))
```

*I know I can to it manually, by implementing a method like `astuple()`. I would like to, if possible, achieve it by calling `tuple` constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve desired functionality by defining `__iter__()` method in your class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, **values):
        self._value_tuple = tuple(values)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self._value_tuple.__iter__()
        # or return iter(self._value_tuple)


foo = Foo(ham=1, eggs=2, spam=3)
print(tuple(foo))
```

Output:

```
('ham', 'eggs', 'spam')
```

If you want `(keys, values)`, you can store your items in dict:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, **values):
        self._value_dict = values

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._value_dict.items())


foo = Foo(ham=1, eggs=2, spam=3)
print(tuple(foo))
```

Prints:

```
(('ham', 1), ('eggs', 2), ('spam', 3))
```

`__iter__()` is part of [Python Datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__). When you implement this method in your class, all functions and syntax constructs that expect something iterable will work with your class without change, that includes parameters in `tuple()`.

Comment: Cool, this works. (`values.items()` instead of `values` though, I've updated my answer). Can you please explain why `__iter__` gives me this functionality? It seems pretty magical right now. (Why `__iter__` of all the dunder methods)

Comment: @AnriofAstora [tuple()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-tuple) consumes an iterable object.

Comment: Oh, ok, I get it. Thank you for the responses.